# Difference between docusign developer account and paid account

Tags: docusignapi

So I have been using docusign developer account for performing in-person and remote signing using docusign APIs. I am interesting in knowing 2 things:

1. The developer account (with the base url account-d.docusign.com) seems to be working fine for me. Why can't I use it for production as well. What difference/advantage does the paid account(with API access) has? What changes exactly when the integration app that I am using for docusigning goes live from "demo", other than the base url (i.e., account.docusign.com)?
2. When I login to my account, and go to **Settings > Integrations > Apps & Keys**, I can see a value "baseUrl" under "API Username" and "API Account ID", this value is either "https://na3.docusign.net" or "https://demo.docusign.net". However, when I use either of these values in my code to perform in-person or remote signing, it gives error. I have to use url account-d.docusign.com, then the API calls work correctly. What is the use of baseUrl mentioned in the portal then? Does it change when the integration app goes live? In our old app we just changed the url in code from account-d.docusign.com to just account.docusign.com when app went live and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Production accounts are the only ones you can use for "real" i.e. valid signatures for legal purposes. Developer account (demo) is for developing, testing, showing what can be done to customers etc. You need to follow the [Go-Live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/) process to enable your integration in production.
2. the **baseURL** is for API calls, not for authentication. And like you indicated, it's different in each env. If your code already handles this - you don't need to worry about it, but this is not the URL for the web app, rather the URL to make API calls.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I used most of the code from docusign SDK. The SDK itself determines the base URL to fetch the API calls. This is done based on the credentials provided I suppose. I only had to change the auth URL from account-d.docusign.com to account.docusign.com. If using developer account, then base URL is demo.docusign.net and if using a go-live account then it is na3.docusign.net (mostly)